# Passing Object from factory to the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a factory that makes an ajax request to some API and then returns an object of data. My code is:

```
app.factory('Test', function($http, $q) {
    var data = {response:{}};
    var getMessages = function() {
        $http.get('https://someapi.com').then(
            function(jsonAPI) {            
                var dataObj = {};
                var messages = [];

                $.each(jsonAPI.data.data, function(x, data) {
                    dataObj[x] = data;
                    $.each(jsonAPI.data.included, function(y, included) {
                        if(data.relationships.sender.data.id == included.id) {
                            dataObj[x].sender = included;
                        }
                    });
                    messages.push(dataObj[x]);
                });
                data.response = messages;
            },
            function(errorResponse) {
            // todo handle error.
            }
        );      
    };
    getMessages();

    return {
        data
    };
});
```

However when I try to remove the 'response' attribute from the data object that is created and have `data = messages` instead of `data.response = messages` the data object is not getting filled. If I keep the response attribute then in my controller when I try to `console.log(Test.data['response'])` I get an empty object. `console.log(Test.data)` returns a valid object though. What am I missing here?

Comment: This will work to populate the view if pass `data.response` through the scope....but you are having problems logging it because `$http` is asynchronous. When you make it a primitive there is no inheritance and so angular won't detect changes

Comment: @charlietfl Then how can I log Test.data and not Test.data['response']?

Comment: Far more common to return promise ...and set scope in promise callback. Will give you solution in a minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep data stored in factory you can store the promise returned by `$http` and have that promise resolve with the stored data.

```
app.factory('Test', function($http, $q) {

    var data = null, dataPromise = null;

    function getMessages() {

        if (!dataPromise) {
            dataPromise = $http.get('https://someapi.com').then(
                    function (jsonAPI) {
                        var dataObj = {};
                        var messages = [];

                        $.each(jsonAPI.data.data, function (x, data) {
                            dataObj[x] = data;
                            $.each(jsonAPI.data.included, function (y, included) {
                                if (data.relationships.sender.data.id == included.id) {
                                    dataObj[x].sender = included;
                                }
                            });
                            messages.push(dataObj[x]);
                        });
                        data = messages;

                        return data;

                    },
                    function (errorResponse) {
                        // todo handle error.
                    }
            );
        }

        return dataPromise

    }

    return {
        getMessages : getMessages
    };

});
```

then in any controller or directive or resolve:

```
Test.getMessages().then(function(messages){
    $scope.messages = messages;
});
```

Comment: This worked fine! Just one more question, this logic seems to me like more of a service than a factory. How would I change it to become a service?

Comment: they are pretty much the same ... just service uses constructor with `this` members and factory returns an object. Can google `difference angular service factory` .. quite a few posts here and articles on web